# Express Set Custom Parameter Query Starter

Tags: express

I'm using express to interact with discord's oauth2 api.

When I request a user oauth token the server responds with a url like:

```
http://localhost:3000/index#token_type=Bearer&access_token=tkn&expires_in=int
```

I'm trying to extract the parameters after the `#` as with discords api parameters start with `#` unlike others which start with a `?`

Because it doesn't start with a question mark I am unable to use the `req.params.x` property.

I thought, "No big deal, ill just get the url and extract it myself" but every single url accessor in express removes string after `#`. This includes `req.url` and `req.originalUrl` which both return the file path.

So how can I get url parameters started by hashtags instead of question marks?
*Or* How can I get the full url *with* content after hashtags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by setting a custom query parser. Code snippet below.

```js
const app = express();

app.set('query parser', (query) => {
    return query.split('&').map(item => {
        const [key, value] = item.split('=');
        return {
            key,
            value
        }
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.originalUrl); // Full URL starting with file path
})
```